# Animate contents of a subview loaded from a nib

Tags: uiview, jquery-animate, subview, nib

I have a uiviewcontroller that contains a uiview as a subview.
The idea is to change the uiview displayed (loading the uiview to display from a nib) by clicking on a button.
Currently I made it, by overriding the initWithFrame: method, by doing:

```
    self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myUIView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now, it loads perfectly. I can change between views with no problems, but, 
in one of my views, I have a button: when the user clicks it, it's supposed to show an uipicker sliding from the bottom (initially hidden) to the center of the view. Altough I'm implementing the IBAction, and using:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay: 0 options: 0 animations:
    ^(void) { 
    _myPicker.frame = theNewFrame;
    }
    completion: nil];
```

When I hit the button, nothing happens. No animation is shown.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance